# as3 zip and unzip files using airxzip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, zip, unzip

I would like to use airxzip but I don't know how to download the source file and where to place it if I do.

I am sorry for being such a newbie at this.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Below is the link to the zip/unzip as3 code I am trying to access.

http://flex.coltware.com/2010/05/01/as3-zip-unzip-lib-airxzip/

Below is a sample to "unzip" but again I don't know how to download the files for importing.

```
// ActionScript file
import com.coltware.airxzip.ZipEntry;
import com.coltware.airxzip.ZipError;
import com.coltware.airxzip.ZipFileReader;
import com.coltware.airxzip.*;

import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

use namespace zip_internal;

public function unzip_init(filename:String):ZipFileReader{
        var reader:ZipFileReader = new ZipFileReader();
        var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(filename);
        reader.open(file);
        return reader;
}

public function unzip_sample1():void{
        var reader:ZipFileReader = unzip_init("new_airxzip.zip");
        var list:Array = reader.getEntries();

        for each(var entry:ZipEntry in list){

                if(entry.isDirectory()){
                        log.debug("DIR  --->" + entry.getFilename());
                }
                else{
                        log.debug("FILE --->" + entry.getFilename() + "(" + entry.getCompressRate() + ")");
                }
        }
}

public function unzip_sample2():void{
        var reader:ZipFileReader = unzip_init("new_airxzip.zip");
        var list:Array = reader.getEntries();

        for each(var entry:ZipEntry in list){
                if(!entry.isDirectory()){
                        if(entry.getFilename() == "sample.txt"){
                                var bytes:ByteArray = reader.unzip(entry);
                                log.debug("sample.txt : " + bytes);
                        }
                }
        }
}

public function unzip_sample3():void{
        var reader:ZipFileReader = unzip_init("crypto_airxzip.zip");
        reader.setPassword("pass");
        var list:Array = reader.getEntries();

        for each(var entry:ZipEntry in list){
                if(!entry.isDirectory()){
                        if(entry.getFilename() == "sample.txt"){
                                try{
                                        var bytes:ByteArray = reader.unzip(entry);
                                        log.debug("sample.txt : " + bytes);
                                }
                                catch(e:ZipError){
                                        log.warn(entry.getFilename() + ":" + e.message);
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
public function unzip_sample4():void{
        var reader:ZipFileReader = unzip_init("abc.zip");
        var list:Array = reader.getEntries();
        for each(var entry:ZipEntry in list){
                entry.dumpLogInfo();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### **`Flash Builder`**

---

**`1. Download the SWC File.` [airxzip](http://code.google.com/p/airxzip/downloads/detail?name=coltware_airxzip_v1_0_1.swc&can=2&q=)**

[image]

---

**`2. In your flash builder project make a`libs`folder. and downloaded SWC files drag and drop or copy.`**

[image]
[image]

---

**`3. In your project mouse right click and Properties click.`**

[image]

---

**`4. Actionscript Build Path - Library Path - Add SWC Folder click and input a libs`**

[image]
[image]

---

---

### **`Flash (below image Mac OS)`**

**`1. File-ActionScript Settings Click`**

[image]

---

**`2. Browse to SWC File icon Click. and downloaded your SWC File link.`**
[image]
[image]

---

**`3. publish setting, Target set a AIR2.5 or AIR 3.X ios or AIR 3.X Android.`**

[image]

---

**`4. check out below my sample code. I tested.`**
here is a sample code. [simple_unzip](http://www.datafilehost.com/download-ee5e9ef7.html)

```
import com.coltware.airxzip.ZipEntry;
import com.coltware.airxzip.ZipError;
import com.coltware.airxzip.ZipFileReader;
import com.coltware.airxzip.*;

import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.FileFilter;

var file:File;
var fileReference:FileReference;
var fileFilter:FileFilter;

function unzip_init():void{

    fileFilter = new FileFilter("selected your zip file.", "*.zip; .gz2; .bz2;");
    file = new File();
    file.browseForOpen("\Users", [fileFilter]);
    file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSelectedFile);
}

function onSelectedFile(e:Event):void
{
    var reader:ZipFileReader = new ZipFileReader();
    reader.open(file);

    var list:Array = reader.getEntries();

        for each(var entry:ZipEntry in list){

                if(entry.isDirectory()){
                        trace("DIR  --->" + entry.getFilename());
                }
                else{
                        trace("FILE --->" + entry.getFilename() + "(" + entry.getCompressRate() + ")");
                }
        }
}

unzip_init();
```

from now, possible check out the sample code. default Environment has been completed.

`What's the SWC?`

> an Adobe SWC file is a package of precompiled Flash symbols and
>   ActionScript code that allows a Flash or Flex developer to distribute
>   classes and assets, or to avoid recompiling symbols and code that will
>   not change.

Comment: This is OUTSTANDING work. The only issue is I don't have flex. I am using Flash Professional. Will this work for that? For some reason flash won't open it.

Comment: Actually, all I really want to do is zip and unzip files using adobe air. I am hoping to use this in apps on droid and ios. So I need it to work on both platforms using air. Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: AMAZING! So this does not save them correct it just unzips them?